# "Eject usb-drive" action for pcmanfm

Tags: lubuntu, usb-drive, .desktop, pcmanfm, eject

I wonder if there's a way to create custom pcmanfm action for ejecting usb-drive in lubuntu? I've tried to do this with [udisksctl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/udisksctl.1.html) but the `--object-path` option is giving me this error:

```
(udisksctl unmount:10926): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_object_manager_get_object: assertion 'g_variant_is_object_path (object_path)' failed
Error looking up object with path /media/user/Flash-Drive
```

And there's no difference of MIME-types between simple folder and mounted drive so "Eject" action is shown on all folders.

### Update

Well, it's seems I've found some kind of solution. This is will unmount and power-off your usb-drive

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Action
Tooltip=Eject selected flash drive
Name=Eject flash drive
Profiles=profile-zero;
Icon=media-eject

[X-Action-Profile profile-zero]
MimeTypes=inode/directory;
Exec=gksudo eject %f
Name=Default profile
```

Also you can use it without gksudo prompt after adding `setuid` to `/usr/bin/eject`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Action
Tooltip=Eject selected flash drive
Name=Eject flash drive
Profiles=profile-zero;
Icon=media-eject

[X-Action-Profile profile-zero]
MimeTypes=inode/directory;
Exec=eject %f
Name=Default profile
```

But this action will be shown on all folders. I still have no idea how to make a difference between usb-drive directory and flash-drive directory. I've seen specification `Basenames` for .desktop entry which specifies selected file-name (used in [empty trash action](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/323-lubuntu-trusty-empty-trash-menu)) so may be there some way to specify file-placement?

### Update 2

Okay, I've found appropriate MIME-type according to [MIME-info Database](http://standards.freedesktop.org/shared-mime-info-spec/shared-mime-info-spec-latest.html) - `inode/mount-point`, but now action isn't shown on any directory at all. What may cause a problem?

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Action
Tooltip=Eject selected drive
Name=Eject drive
Profiles=profile-zero;
Icon=media-eject

[X-Action-Profile profile-zero]
MimeTypes=inode/mount-point
Exec=eject %f
Name=Default profile
```

Comment: What is the exact command?

Comment: udisksctl unmount --object-path /media/user/Flash-Drive

Comment: There is no file called `/media/user/Flash-Drive`

Comment: This is where my usb-drive automatically mounts. I think i just don't understand --object-path  option?

Comment: No, your USB mounts at `/media/YOURUSERNAME/USBNAME` You have to replace `user` and `Flash-Drive` with the correct names.

Comment: You have created the file.desktop? What is their content?

Comment: @kyodake yes, but it's not working and there's nothing special, just trying to call script with %f parameter. Script is using udiskctl to unmount and power-off dirve. The problem is udisksctl isn't working for me even from command line. The other problem is MIME-type of desktop link to usb-drive which is inode/directory

Comment: @NicholasV. it is something to do with it needing an object not a path: http://askubuntu.com/questions/633037/what-is-an-object-path/633045#633045

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use the `umount` command.

With the `fdisk -l` command and inserting different usb-drives determined as identified, say they are `/dev/sdd1`

Before creating the actions (file.desktop), create its directory:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/file-manager/actions
```

Create and edit the action file (umount.desktop) by using these terminal commands one at a time:

```
touch ~/.local/share/file-manager/actions/umount.desktop
nano ~/.local/share/file-manager/actions/umount.desktop
```

Paste the below content in umount.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Action
Name=Eject Usb-Drive
Icon=dialog-password
Profiles=profile-zero;

[X-Action-Profile profile-zero]
Exec=umount /dev/sdd1
Name=Default profile
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made more progress on this, but solution is still not ideal:
I am using Lubuntu 16.04 with PCManFM 1.24.  For USB pen drives I get "Eject Removable Media", but for USB disk drives, I do not get "Safely Remove Drive" as you do in Nautilus (I only get Unmount).
First issue is to get right-click context on devices where, unfortunately, it seems actions are not supported for devices in the left pane in PCManFM, (or Nautilus, but actions work in left pane in Nemo, but actions are implemented differently in Nemo).
I have a work-a-round to this by showing "Devices" icon in left pane by ticking "Devices" under "Show in Places" in Edit-Preferences-Layout, where you can then right click on the device in the right pane as shown in attached link:
[pcmanfm devices right click image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJoUf.png)

Second issue is script to safely remove drive:
The argument passed to action script in the above example is:
computer:///ST1000LM010-9YH146.drive (or just ST1000LM010-9YH146 with %w)
which is not ideal - I don't believe it evenly uniquely identifies drive as it does not include the serial number.  Below is output from "udisksctl status":

```
$ udisksctl status
MODEL                     REVISION  SERIAL               DEVICE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
WDC WD5000BEVT-22ZAT0     01.01A01  WD-WX70A9903180      sda
Kingston DataTraveler G3  1.00      001CC0EC31D0F081F6071284 sdb
ST1000LM010-9YH146        CC9F      W2M076TD             sdc
```

So my script matches the model, so assumes you do not have 2 identical devices plugged in to pick up the device.
To implement script create file     ~/.local/share/filemanager/actions/eject.desktop
containing:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Action
Name=Safely Remove Drive
Icon=drive-harddisk-usb
Profiles=profile-zero;

[X-Action-Profile profile-zero]
MimeTypes=inode/mount-point
Exec=/home/mike/.local/share/file-manager/actions/eject.sh %w 
Name=Default profile
```

I have put the script, eject.sh, specified by "Exec" in ~/.local/share/filemanager/actions, but note you cannot use "~" or "$HOME" in a desktop file so you have to specify complete path as I have done above

Script eject.sh should contain:

```
device=`udisksctl status | awk -v d=$1 '
BEGIN {
    gsub("%20"," ",d)
    sub("$"," ",d)  # Add a space on the end to give a more exact match
    sub("^","^",d) # Add ^ to start to give a more exact match
    }
$0 ~ d {
    print "/dev/"$NF
    }' `
if [ "$device" == "/dev" ]
then
    echo "Removable device not found"
else
    for dev in `df | awk -v device=$device '$1 ~ device {print $1}' `
    do
        echo "Unmounting "$dev
        udisksctl unmount -b $dev
    done

    echo "Powering off: "$device
    udisksctl power-off -b $device
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer does use pcmanfm, but I have found it is the most convenient one. TL;DR; use lxpanel to add an icon to gnome-disks.

In details:

In lxpanel right-click and select 'Add / Remove Panel Items'. Add a new 'Application Launch Bar' and position it before (or somewhere around) 'Digital Clock' that should be already there. In the newly added 'Application Launch Bar' add as application the 'Preferences / Disks'. This is the gnome-disks application that comes with Lubuntu.

If you need to do something with your disks, then just click the Disks icon in the panel. You select the disk and Power Off from the top menu.

This is same as handy as 'Safely remove hardware' in Windows OS, and the above positions it more or less in same place as the Windows has it in desktop.

Comment: Thanks you! I'll certainly will try to use your solution.

Comment: @ppp, thanks, this is really handy (and sorry for such a late comment :). The only thing missing is a possibility to assign a hotkey for certain actions / disks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your command

```
udisksctl unmount --object-path /media/user/Flash-Drive
```

is wrong.

`/media/user/Flash-Drive` isn't an object path.

---

1. Find the object path with this command:

   ```
   $ gdbus introspect --system --dest org.freedesktop.UDisks --object-path /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices --recurse --only-properties | grep -E "(readonly .+ (Device(IsMounted|IsDrive|File|MountPaths) ).*|\}|.*\{)" | awk -v RS="};" '/Flash-Drive/'

     node /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sdc1 {
       interface org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device {
           readonly as DeviceMountPaths = ['/media/user/Flash-Drive'];
           readonly b DeviceIsMounted = true;
           readonly b DeviceIsDrive = false;
           readonly s DeviceFile = '/dev/sdc1';
   ```
2. Take the node `/org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sdc1` via:

   (replace `'/\/media\/user\/Flash-Drive/'` with your path).

   ```
   $ gdbus introspect --system --dest org.freedesktop.UDisks --object-path /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices --recurse --only-properties | grep -E "(readonly .+ (Device(IsMounted|IsDrive|File|MountPaths) ).*|\}|.*\{)" | awk -v RS="};" '/\/media\/user\/Flash-Drive/' | awk '/node/ {print $2}'

   /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sdc1
   ```
3. and unmount with

   ```
   gdbus call --system --dest org.freedesktop.UDisks --object-path /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sdc1 --method org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device.FilesystemUnmount []
   ```

   *Or as AllInOne  (replace `'/\/media\/user\/Flash-Drive/'` with your path):*

   ```
   gdbus call --system --dest org.freedesktop.UDisks --object-path $(gdbus introspect --system --dest org.freedesktop.UDisks --object-path /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices --recurse --only-properties | grep -E "(readonly .+ (Device(IsMounted|IsDrive|File|MountPaths) ).*|\}|.*\{)" | awk -v RS="};" '/\/media\/user\/Flash-Drive/' | awk '/node/ {print $2}') --method org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device.FilesystemUnmount []
   ```

Comment: You can use `--block-device` too for a slightly saner interface. You'd still need to look up which block device you needed though.