# What is an object path?

Tags: paths

[This man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/udisksctl.1.html) has the following section:

```
udisksctl unmount {--object-path OBJECT | --block-device DEVICE}
```

What is an OBJECT? I tried to give it a path (i.e. `media/tim/name`) but it doesn't accept that.

What do I need to tell it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UDisks2 uses D-Bus "objects". These are essentially paths to data structures.

Here's how [the manual](http://udisks.freedesktop.org/docs/latest/ref-dbus-udisks2-well-known-object.html) puts it:

> The process that owns the well-known D-Bus name [org.freedesktop.UDisks2](http://udisks.freedesktop.org/docs/latest/ref-dbus-overview.html#ref-dbus-well-known-name) on the system bus (typically [udisksd](http://udisks.freedesktop.org/docs/latest/udisksd.8.html)) exports an object at the well-known path `/org/freedesktop/UDisks2`.  This object implements the [org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#standard-interfaces-objectmanager) interface and should be used by clients to discover other objects.

Comment: Which in turn you can receive with `udisksctl dump`.