# How do I find and use `--object-path` with `udisksctl`?

Tags: unmount, udisks

I don't understand the `--object-path` option in the `udisksctl` command

I want to unmount an USB thumb drive, but I don't want to have to lookup it's device name (for example /dev/sdb) at each mount. The device name can change across mounts. I want a static way to identify the drive, for example by its partition name or UUID. Does the `--object-path` service this function?

How do I identify what the `--object-path` is of a USB thumb drive so I can execute a command such as the following with a partition name that is static across mountings: `udisksctl unmount --object-path /media/greg/FD-ext4`

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the answer to the same question, but there isn't a clear answer because the object seems to be the internal D-Bus object that is created by `udisksd` (see: https://askubuntu.com/a/633045/49873).  This is even more annoying when you have multiple disks mounted and you want to unmount one of them.

My workaround to this is to continue to use the `--block-device` (or `-b`) option, but by disk label, e.g. my external backup drive has the label `xbackup`, so I can mount it as:

```
$ udisksctl mount -b /dev/disk/by-label/xbackup
```

Note that this can be confusing if you have multiple drives with the same label.  I believe in that scenario the first drive attached to the system retains the label as is, and subsequent devices get a numeric suffix, like `xbackup1` (unverified, trying to recall from memory).

Comment: How do you label the encrypted partition? If I tried to use e2label, I got "/dev/sda1 contains a crypto_LUKS file system"

Comment: @josircg I would imagine you need to do that when you setup the encrypted partition (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/538622).  I don't know if you can do that on existing LUKS partitions though.

Comment: +1; I tried `/dev/disk/by-uuid/<the actual UUID of the partition to mount>` and it works well for me.